# Apache2, 2 websites, 1 regular with auth, another 1 with rewrite rule to pass a domain to another website on different port

Tags: server, apache2

I have a ubuntu apache2, I have quickbox setup and been running for awhile and wanted to switch from plex to jellyfin but jellyfin runs its own web server on port 8086 so wanted to just be simple

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
SSLPassPhraseDialog  builtin
SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/var/cache/mod_ssl/scache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  3600
#SSLMutex default
SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
SSLCryptoDevice builtin

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName jelly.WEBSITE.com
  ServerAlias www.jelly.WEBSITE.com

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =jelly.WEBSITE.com
RewriteRule ^ http://IP:8096/$1 [P]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]


ProxyPassReverse "/" "http://IP:8096/"

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/socket
RewriteRule ^ ws://IP:8096/$1 [P]

ProxyPassReverse "/socket" "ws://IP:8096/socket"
  ProxyPassReverse "/socket" "ws://IP:8096/socket"  
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/jelly.WEBSITE.com.error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
        # alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn 
  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/jelly.WEBSITE.com.error.log

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName box.WEBSITE.com
        DocumentRoot "/srv/rutorrent/home"
        <Directory "/srv/rutorrent/home/">
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All AuthConfig
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        AuthType Digest
        AuthName "rutorrent"
        AuthUserFile '/etc/htpasswd'
        Require valid-user
        </Directory>
SCGIMount /cyber 127.0.0.1:41041
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =box.WEBSITE.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
Options +Indexes +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
ServerName box.WEBSITE.com
SSLEngine on
        DocumentRoot "/srv/rutorrent/home"
        <Directory "/srv/rutorrent/home/">
                Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
                AllowOverride All AuthConfig
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        AuthType Digest
        AuthName "rutorrent"
        AuthUserFile '/etc/htpasswd'
        Require valid-user
        </Directory>
        SSLProtocol +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2
        SSLHonorCipherOrder On
        SSLCipherSuite ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
        SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*"nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
        SCGIMount /cyber 127.0.0.1:41041
        ServerName box.WEBSITE.com
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/box.WEBSITE.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/box.WEBSITE.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
SCGIMount /cyber 127.0.0.1:41041
```

been trying for a few days with bard.google help and jelly keeps getting the auth from box also jelly randomly gets too many redirects.